# Debunk social media post anti-Jainism and Buddhism

Tags: bhagavata-purana

> # Jainism is the root of sin, Vishnu will be appearing for their destruction. *Padma Purana II.38.25.30*
>
> # Buddhism & Jainism are false religions. *Padma P 6.23.5-7; Matsya P 24.47-49*
>
> # Touching a Jain, Mlecha, Chandala makes one impure. *Vaya P 17.24-25; Brahmand P 2.3.14.88; Usana Smriti 5.30-32*
>
> # Visnu incarnated as Buddha to deceive people. *Srimad B 2.3.37; Agni P 16.1-5*
>
> # Killing those who convert to other religions especially Buddhism & Jainism. *Vishnu P book 3 ch 17 & 18; Shiva P 2.5.4.1; 2.5.6.28 & 2.5.4.1; Srimad B 5.26.14-15; Matsya P 24.47-49*

[This picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaSOe.jpg) is posted a lot on social media. Can it be debunked?

Comment: Most are made up quotes as scriptures like Puranas do not talk about Jainism.

Comment: Please note mahapuranas are compilations that came after the 11th century. They are no more than thousands of years old and have undergone multiple modifications, hence they are contradictory, opinion-based, and have comments on other faiths and practices. Smriti means - something that has been written down from memory and aren't accurate. The parts that have opinions and are later modifications are meant to be rejected.

Comment: @User29449 then why mahabharat and chandryog upnishad mention 'purans'

Comment: @Hope They make distinctions between **puranas** and **itihaas**, making former as **mythical**, and later one as **real**. Btw, its a very common sense, *Mahapuranas* came after thousands of years after Mahabharata, the puranas Mahabharata are talking literally means - mythical stories, not the version that you are referring now.

Comment: @User29449 but how are you sure they are based on opinion because they predicted future like they were anti vedic religion. From Book VII - Jain Ramayana (Rāmāyaṇa)

Daśānana with Śambūka and Lakṣmaṇa are in the fourth hell

Rāma had four chief queens: Maithilī, Prabhāvatī, Ratinibhā, and Śrīdāmā, the fourth . So, my opinion tells me they predicted they are against holy vedas and it's teachings. Also author of puranas:ved vyas. So, I think just because of 5-6prakshipt you can't prove that it's fake/ mythical. Well, I can agree to symbolic meaning point.

Comment: @Hope Prediction of future is no big deal, also this isn't a quite of prediction, even before Jain Ramayana, there were a couple more Ramayanas existing too. Yes it is true that Jain is pretty anti-vedic. But this is not a prediction, puranas were composed well after the advent of Jainism, Chiristianity and Islam. No. Author of Puranas isn't **Ved Vyas!**. Puran: literally means - mythical old story/made-up story. (https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3&dir=au#:~:text=BV-,%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A3,makeup,-BV)

Comment: @User29449 after "after Christianity and  Islam ,purans were written "you have learnt history from mythology books. I bet.

Comment: @Hope If this is mythology: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puranas#:~:text=It%20is%20not%20possible,1000%20CE.%5B9%5D then it is still better than puranic mythology.

Comment: @User29449 still it's before islam

Comment: @Hope Puranas came from 350 C.E. to 1000 C.E. (The majority of today's are barely just thousands of years old!). Islam started in 610 C.E. The Majority of Puranas that we read today, were compiled almost 400 years after Islam. [Check, I've written an answer citing various sources and historians somehere]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a fact Jainism and Buddhism are considered heretic and delusory paths in all Hindu scriptures. All orthodox acharyas also accept this.

[Padma purana bhumi khanda ch 38](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364245.html)

> 25-30. When Kali (-yuga) sets in, all men, deluded by sins, will act
> after having resorted to the Jaina faith. Men will abandon Vedic
> practices, and will commit sins. There is no doubt that the Jaina
> faith is the root of sin. O best king, the fall of those men, who are
> heaps of sins, is brought about by this great delusion. Govinda (i.e.
> Viṣṇu), the destroyer of all sins, will be (appearing) for their
> destruction and for nothing else. Taking the form of his liking he
> will restrain (them) from sins. When sins wil have thus accumulated,
> he, the god will be (appearing) as Kalki[2](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/2/7/37/) for the destruction of the
> Mlecchas; there is no doubt about it. Give up the behaviour of (i.e.
> proper for) Kali (-yuga) and resort to merit. Behave truthfully;
> become the guardian of your subjects.

[SB 2.7.37](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/2/7/37/)

> When the atheists, after being well versed in the Vedic scientific
> knowledge, annihilate inhabitants of different planets, flying unseen
> in the sky on well-built rockets prepared by the great scientist Maya,
> the Lord will bewilder their minds by dressing Himself attractively as
> Buddha and will preach on subreligious principles.

[Agni Purana 16.2-4](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083104.html)

> 2. They sought refuge in the lord saying, “Protect us! Protect us!”. He (Viṣṇu), who is of the form of illusory delusion became the son of
>    Śuddhodana. 3-4. He deluded those demons. Those, who had abandoned the
>    path laid down in the Vedas, became the Bauddhas and from them others
>    who had abandoned the Vedas. He then became the Arhat (Jaina). He then
>    made others as Arhats. Thus the heretics came into being devoid of
>    vedic dharmas.

[Vayu Purana II.17.24-25](https://archive.org/details/the-vayu-purana-part-2-ancient-indian-tradition-and-mythology/page/620/mode/2up?view=theater)

[image]

The scriptures do not advocate Vaidikas to kill Jainas or Buddhists. However, it is said That Lord Vishnu, When he incarnates as Kalki will kill all Buddhists,atheists and mlecchas and protect dharma.

**Kalki Purana 10.30**[image]

Comment: Yess sir also he deluded Daityas.

Comment: Could the killing refer to conversion over slaughter, ie the killing of the buddhist dharma and jain dharma

Comment: @Haridasa Nope. The purana describes a full fledged war between Buddhists and Lord Kalki where he exterminates them.

Comment: Ooh a war, so both sides fight each other?

Comment: Basically Yes @Haridasa

Comment: Also I cannot find the verse in Mahabharta which talks about eternal hell is this true?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32293/what-is-the-scriptural-basis-for-eternal-hell-as-madhvas-believes

Comment: @Haridasa That is in Vana parva. "Yudhishthira answered,--'He that summoneth a poor Brahmana promising to make him a gift and then tells him that he hath nothing to give, goeth to everlasting hell. He also must go to everlasting hell, who imputes falsehood to the Vedas, the scriptures, the Brahmanas, the gods, and the ceremonies in honour of the Pitris, He also goeth to everlasting hell who though in possession of wealth, never giveth away nor enjoyeth himself from avarice, saying, he hath none." https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03311.htm

Comment: Theirs no way of making the hell non-eternal?

Comment: Depends upon the interpretations. One can intepret the eternality stated here as relative and not absolute.

Comment: Ahh so as in a really long time, but not absolute.

Comment: I am just wondering what word is eternity translated over here?

Comment: The samskrita says 'सोऽक्षयंनरकं व्रजेत्'. 'Akshaya Naraka' in a literal sense would translate to eternal/everlasting hell.

Comment: How I interpret is Sanatana means eternal forever and Akshaya is the feeling of imperishability and undecaying, so an inexhaustibly long time.

Answer (score 4):

Srimad bhagvatam canto 2 chapter 3 has only [25 verses](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/2/3/25/)

Vayu puran chapter 17 only have [7 verses](https://archive.org/details/VayuPuranaG.V.TagarePart1)

Matasya puran chapter 24(this verse do not says to kill any jain)

> Brihaspati then went and deluded the other sons of Raji with *false*
> *philosophy and established the Jain religion opposed to the vedas,*
> though himself a knower of the Vedas and Indra on finding the ***sons of***
> ***Brihaspati*** propagating a religion different from the Vedas based on a
> show of reason only killed them with his mighty thunderbolt.-47-49

I will not deny that jainism and buddhism are false religions because

> या वेदबाह्याः स्मृतयो याश्च काश्च कुदृष्टयः ।
>
> सर्वास्ता निष्फलाः प्रेत्य तमोनिष्ठा हि ताः स्मृताः ॥ ९५ ॥
>
> उत्पद्यन्ते च्यवन्ते च यान्यतोऽन्यानि कानि चित् ।
>
> तान्यर्वाक्कालिकतया निष्फलान्यनृतानि च ॥ ९६ ॥
>
> Those ‘revealed texts’ that are outside the Veda, as also all the
> ***false theories, are useless, even when carried to perfection***; as they have been declared to be founded on ‘darkness.’—(95)
>
> Those other (doctrines) which spring up and ***perish are all
> worthless and false***, being of modern growth.—(96)
>
> From manusmriti ch 12

Usana smriti chapter 5 [verse 30-32](https://archive.org/details/ushana-smriti-ii-english) doesn't even mention jainism, it just talk about avoiding few people(Mlechas,person of grim visage)during meals at a S'rdddha

It is nowhere said to kill others like [shiv puran 2.5.4.1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226145.html)

And shrimad bhagvatam 5.26.14-15

> 14.The killer of a brāhmaṇa is put into the hell known as
> Kālasūtra...... Therefore he sometimes lies down, sometimes sits,
> sometimes stands up and sometimes runs here and there. He must suffer
> in this way for as many thousands of years as there are hairs on the
> body of an animal.
>
> 15. If a person deviates from the path of the Vedas in the absence of
>     an emergency, the *servants of Yamarāja put him into the hell called
>     Asi-patravana, where they beat him with whips.* When he runs hither
>     and thither, fleeing from the extreme pain, on all sides he runs into
>     palm trees with leaves like sharpened swords. Thus injured all over
>     his body and fainting at every step, he cries out, “Oh, what shall I
>     do now! How shall I be saved!” This is *how one suffers who deviates
>     from the accepted religious principles*

14 verse simply says not to kill a brahman (learner of vedas) otherwise you will be given xyz punishments in hell.

15 verse explain about punishment for non vedic activities or for those who gave up vedic practices(it no where says to kill anyone as all this would be done by yama guards)

***After reading the answer you may have 1 question:Why buddhism and jainism are anti vedic***

Answer :because of scriptures(non sanatni scripture promoting anti vedic ideas)

*Note:these are not scripture of hinduism*

From Book VII - Jain Ramayana (Rāmāyaṇa)

> Daśānana with Śambūka and ***Lakṣmaṇa are in the [fourth hell](https://www.wisdomlib.org/jainism/book/trishashti-shalaka-purusha-caritra/d/doc214126.html)***

> Rāma had [four chief queens](https://www.wisdomlib.org/jainism/book/trishashti-shalaka-purusha-caritra/d/doc214083.html): Maithilī, Prabhāvatī, Ratinibhā, and
> Śrīdāmā, the fourth .

So, if jainism promote all this ;that's why it is unworthy and false .

In Brahmajāla [Sutta](https://www.wisdomlib.org/buddhism/book/the-brahmaj%C4%81la-sutta/d/doc52024.html) of buddhism they criticize various ideas of holy vedas and darshan granth

To know about [false allegations and truth read this](http://satyarthprakash.in/english/chapter-twelve/)

Comment: False and useless as they eventually lead to abandoning of Dharma.

Comment: Talking about those religions mentioned above.