# As per Hinduism, What happens to those who follow Nihilist Philosophies like Buddhism?

Tags: philosophy, buddhism, hell, non-hindu, buddha

Since Buddhism is regarded as a  [heretic path as per all the scriptures of hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58164/34000),

What would ultimately happen to those who follow Nihilst philosophies like Buddhism as per hinduism?

Will Buddhists end up in one of the Hindu hells?

Or will they attain the state of complete voidness as espoused by Shunyavadis which would lead them to be completely divorced from Brahman?

Answer (score 0):

> असूर्या नाम ते लोका अन्धेन तमसावृताः।
> तांस्ते प्रेत्याभिगच्छन्ति ये के चात्महनो जनाः॥

> asuryā nāma te lokā andhena tamasāvṛtāḥ
> tāṁste pretyābhigacchanti ye ke cātmahano janāḥ

> Devilish (asurya) are those worlds called, with blind darkness (tamas) covered o’er! Unto them, on deceasing, go whatever folk are slayers of the Self. *-Isha Upanishad verse 3*

Isa Upanishad is one of the principal Upanishads and it is part of the Yajurveda. In fact, Isha Upanishad is the last chapter (chapter 40th) of White Yajurveda Samhita.

It says that after death, people who do not believe in the self go to a devilish world where darkness prevails forever. Buddhists do not accept the presence of the Atman or self. So according to the Vedas, the same fate is awaiting for them.

Also, we found the same opinion in Manusmriti.

> All those traditions (smriti) and **those despicable systems of philosophy, which are not based on the Veda, produce no reward after death**; for they are declared to be founded on Darkness. *-Manusmriti 12.95*

Reference -

1. Upanishads
2. [Manusmriti translated by George Buhler](https://saraswat-prakashan.weebly.com/manusmriti.html)

Comment: There's a good commentary for the verse here: https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/isavasya/isavasya_3.html

Comment: Agreed if one deludes himself into disbelief from an Atma their is no escape and no moksha.